# HTTPS request API for iPhone

Tags: https, request

I have API that looks like
    #https://www.wikifood.eu/wikifood/en/struts/userfoodDB.do?method=getProductOverview&query=4016249502058&startAt=0&limit=5&filter=true&loginname=developer&password=4f14f46f76c4b9be2150be579669e699b79f0093

I need to add it to my application that scan barcodes. So parameter query i need to change to resultText:

```
#https://www.wikifood.eu/wikifood/en/struts/userfoodDB.do?method=getProductOverview&query="resultText"&startAt=0&limit=5&filter=true&loginname=developer&password=4f14f46f76c4b9be2150be579669e699b79f0093
```

Now I need to create request to the DB. And than receive some xml file.

1) How can I do it? If I need only to parse result(xml file) and display it on iPhone?

2) Can result be displayed in ImageView after parsing?

I'm trying to do this now with ASIHTTPRequest http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use, but actually I don't understand what should I do except this:

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
 NSURL *url = [NSURL     URLWithString:@"https://www.wikifood.eu/wikifood/en/struts/userfoodDB.do?method=getProductOverview&query="resultText"&startAt=0&limit=5&filter=true&loginname=NNNNNNNN&password=PPPPPPPPPP"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

}

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
// Use when fetching text data
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
NSError *error = [request error];
}
@end
```

Should I add something alse to the Delegate files or Controller files?

Thanks

Hope to hear from You soon

Comment: How you  accessed ' ASIHTTPRequest '  function ?

Answer (score 0):

So I am using ASIHTTPRequest too.

When I get the data from ...*requestFinished* just put it into a NSDictionary by calling JSON Value (download the api [here](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/))

So for example:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[request responseString] JSONValue];
```

Then you can acces to data in cellForRowAtIndexPath to shop up the data in a tableView.

Got it?

Comment: I think so. I would try to use it. Thanks.